# APC switched PDU rack, lost state after reboot or power loss

Tags: electrical-power, power-distribution-unit

I have the following:

- We have a few APC 7920 PDU's
- Using POWER IQ to control the PDS's via SNMP 1/2
- Using also Mobile Power IQ to control the PDU if need via iPad/iPhone

I am in the process of testing a few scenarios. One which has be stumped me a little.

1. Outlet 1 is on, Outlet 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 is off
2. Power IQ recognizes this
3. Turn off the power to the PDU
4. Wait 2 minutes
5. Turn on the power to the PDU
6. All the outlets are in a state of ON

My question(s),

1. Is it possible to preserver the state of the PDU's outlets after coming back online
2. Is it possible to execute a pre-configured state after coming back online

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your second question.

Comment: @joeqwerty - Hi, When you reboot the APC or it comes on from a power failure, it follows a per-configured state. In this case, outlet 1 - 8 will turn on. I would like, e.g. only outlet 1 to come on and the to stay off. I am not sure where to edit this information as I have looked and the manual and the admin panel. Why do I want to do this. TO prevent a power surge to all the equipment.

Comment: Hi, does anyone have any experience with this or should I conclude that this is not possible? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only had my hands on the larger 7950 models, but I think the logic should apply to all APC switched PDUs.

You can configure each outlet to either power on immediately when power is restored, power up with a delay of up to 7200 seconds or not power up at all:

[image: outlet configuration screenshot]

This is how you get a "preconfigured state" working. I never found anything to have reload the "previous state" - i believe the current state never is stored on any kind of persistent storage.

Comment: Right on!!!! Works a treat